# Multi-Checkpoint System in Godot 4 (3D)

Tags: 3d, game-engine, gdscript, godot4

I am very new to Godot, but have some experience in programming in Python. I am making a 3D simple movement game to learn about the engine, and I want to add checkpoints throughout the level. I followed this tutorial (https://youtu.be/AEdEUeK_g4A) to get most of the code for the checkpoints, but it didn't work. I have spent a few more hours researching and changing the code, and now I am nearly there, I just can't figure out how to get the checkpoint to know where its position is.

I have moved things around from the original tutorial, and now the checkpoint script (extends Area3D) is autoloaded, so I can access it from other scripts. I have tested (with the print function) and it knows when the area has been entered, but when I press to load checkpoint, it takes me back to 0,0,0. I have set the initial check_point_pos vector3 to be 10,10,10, and it brings me there.
So it seems the issue is that the vector3 is not being updated. What do I need to add to make the vector3 update with the correct position for each checkpoint? Ive tried a few things, but nothing is working so far.

```
extends Area3D

var check_point_pos = Vector3.ZERO

func save_check_point(pos_x, pos_y, pos_z):
    check_point_pos.x = pos_x
    check_point_pos.y = pos_y
    check_point_pos.z = pos_z

func _on_area_entered(_body):
    print("checkpoint")
    save_check_point(self.position.x, self.position.y, self.position.z)
```

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("load_checkpoint"):
    set_position(checkpt.check_point_pos)
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFTZp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an3cO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic check point system needs two parts.

- A place to store the last reached check point. Which - following your approach - I will do with an Autoload.
- A check point you place in the world that will store the position when triggered by the player character. This will be an `Area3D`.

---

This is the part of your code that stores the last reached check point (and hence what would be in an Autoload):

```
extends Area3D

var check_point_pos = Vector3.ZERO

func save_check_point(pos_x, pos_y, pos_z):
    check_point_pos.x = pos_x
    check_point_pos.y = pos_y
    check_point_pos.z = pos_z
```

These are the modifications I will do:

- It does not need to be an `Area3D`, it fact it does not need a position in the world. So I'll change it `Node`.
- It does not need a method to save the check point position because we can set the variable directly. So I'll remove `save_check_point`.
- And while I'm at it, I'll set the type of the variable so it is no longer a `Variant`.

This is the result (which, again, is what you will make into an Autoload):

```
extends Node

var check_point_pos:Vector3
```

Make sure you give it a name when making it an Autoload. I believe you are using the name `checkpt`, so I'll use that for this answer.

---

And the `Area3D` you place in the world, has this part of the code:

```
extends Area3D

func _on_area_entered(_body):
    print("checkpoint")
    save_check_point(self.position.x, self.position.y, self.position.z)
```

These are the modifications I'll make:

- We need to use the Autoload to set the variable. And since I have removed `save_check_point`, we will set the variable directly.
- We do not want to use `position` because that is relative to the parent `Node3D`. Instead we will use `global_position` which is relative to the game world origin.
- And while I'm at it, I'll give it a class name, so it shows up in the dialog to add a new node.
- And I'll have it connect the area entered (¿?) to itself.

This is the result:

```
class_name CheckPoint
extends Area3D


func _ready() -> void:
    if not area_entered.is_connected(_on_area_entered):
        area_entered.connect(_on_area_entered)


func _on_area_entered(_area:Area3D) -> void:
    print("checkpoint")
    checkpt.check_point_pos = global_position
```

I would have expected that you would use `body_entered` instead of `area_entered`. Double check that `area_entered` is what you want. If you actually want `body_entered` the code would be like this:

```
class_name CheckPoint
extends Area3D


func _ready() -> void:
    if not body_entered.is_connected(_on_body_entered):
        body_entered.connect(_on_body_entered)


func _on_body_entered(_body:Node3D) -> void:
    print("checkpoint")
    checkpt.check_point_pos = global_position
```

I recommend to change the collision mask so that only the player character will trigger it, and nothing else.

---

Of course, recalling the check point looks like this (in your player character):

```
global_position = checkpt.check_point_pos
```

---

I also want to note that using an `static var` is a viable alternative, this way you do not need an `Autoload` and everything will be in a single script:

```
class_name CheckPoint
extends Area3D


static var check_point_pos:Vector3


func _ready() -> void:
    if not area_entered.is_connected(_on_area_entered):
        area_entered.connect(_on_area_entered)


func _on_area_entered(_area:Area3D) -> void:
    print("checkpoint")
    CheckPoint.check_point_pos = global_position
```

This time recalling the check point looks like this (in your player character):

```
global_position = CheckPoint.check_point_pos
```